# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in block async with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Hi I have a problem when I try to get a value of a global variable or set value. 
The code it's in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method of the app life cycle, this works for me when I need know the state of call in real time but sometimes this generate EXC_BAD_ACCESS

this is the variable declaration `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *calling;` and this is in my .h file.

This is my code of my .m implementation file:

```
__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        while (weakSelf.calling.intValue == 1)
        {
            callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call)
            {
                if([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
                {
                   weakSelf.calling = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] copy];//Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

                }

            };
        }
    }
});
```

But sometimes generate an error and others times not.  Any idea?

Comment: Replace `__unsafe_unretained` with `__weak`. Weak variables will automatically be set to `nil` when the referenced object is deallocated.

Comment: Also, why are you calling `copy` on an immutable `NSNumber` object?

Comment: I used __weak but this not work, and I remove copy of NSNumber but it's not work, :(

Answer (score 4):

Stop using this `weakSelf`. It is not necessary. `self` does not retain this block. There is no retain cycle.

When you say that `__weak` "does not work", it is a sign that `self` has already been deallocated by the time the block runs, so the weak reference has been set to `nil`, thus messages to it do nothing. This is also why `__unsafe_unretained` crashes -- `self` has already been deallocated; without `__weak` to set it to `nil`, it is a dangling pointer.